# Curious double sum identity

Tags: combinatorial-identities

The following identity seems to hold for $a>1$ :

$$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{1}{ \frac{a^m}{m}\left(  \frac{a^m}{m}+ \frac{a^n}{n}  \right) }   = \frac{a^2}{2(a-1)^4}$$

I've tested this with Maple for various values of $a$, but I haven't been able to make any headway on proving it. My usual tricks don't seem to work. I'd be grateful for any ideas or for a proof.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $2$ and replace one of the (two) double sums with the same double sum except with $n$ and $m$ changed. You then wish to show $$\sum_{m=1}^\infty \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{mn}{a^{mn}} = \frac{a^2}{(a-1)^4}.$$

Comment: @mathworker21 Your $a^{mn}$ in the denominator should be $a^{m+n}$ I think, and then your sum is just $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n/a^n$, squared. This sum is $a/(a-1)^2$ by, say, differentiating $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/a^n= 1/(a-1)$.

Comment: @mathworker21, why don't you post your comment as an answer? I'll upvote it.

Comment: Yes, @mathworker, I think you should write this as an answer and I will accept it. Great job. So easy when you lay it out! I'm a little embarrassed, but I'm still delighted by your answer.